# How to dynamically change xsl:output method attribute value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to use the same xslt and test against different outputs, i e, xml, html, xhtml and text; of course I'm doing this:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

OR

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

But I want to dynamically change through an informed parameter, defaulting to xml if I omite it.

I tried this:

```
<xsl:param name="outputMethod" select="xml" />  
<xsl:output method="$outputMethod"indent="yes"/>
```

No success, output is:

```
 XTSE0020: Invalid value for serialization method: must be
  xml|html|xhtml|text|json|adaptive, or a QName in '{uri}local' form
```

and tried this much more convoluted way, I know:

```
<xsl:variable name="thisDocument" select="document('')" /> 
<xsl:param name="outputMethod" select="xml" />  
<xsl:variable name="myOutputMethod" select="$outputMethod"/>
<xsl:output method="$thisDocument/xsl:stylesheet/myOutputMethod" indent="yes"/>
```

No success too, output is:

```
Static error at xsl:output on line 10 column 85 of CopyingNodes.xslt:
  XTSE0020: Both the prefix {$thisDocument/xsl} and the local part
  {stylesheet/myOutputMethod} are invalid
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

So, any corrections? suggestions?

Or is it impossible to dynamically change xsl:output method?

TIA

Comment: Note also that, to bind a variable to the string value `xml`, you need to use `<xsl:param name="outputMethod" select="'xml'" />` and not `<xsl:param name="outputMethod" select="xml" />` as the latter tries to select an element named `xml`.

Comment: All three solutions worked as a charm; thanks MartinHonnen, @Max Toro and Michael Kay; I wish I could mark all 3 as answers. I choose Max Toro's because I saw and tried it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `xsl:result-document`:

```xml
<xsl:param name="method" select="'xml'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
   <xsl:result-document method="{$method}">
      <!-- your code here -->
   </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

With XSLT 3 you can use a shadow attribute and a static parameter:

```
  <xsl:param name="output-method" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'html'"/>

  <xsl:output _method="{$output-method}" indent="yes"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZF/1

Answer (score 1):

As well as the answers supplied by Messrs Honnen and Toro, many XSLT processors allow you to supply serialization parameters from the API or command line; these will generally override anything in the stylesheet. For example with Saxon you can do

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:in.xml -xsl:style.xsl !method=xhtml
```

(The `!` needs to be escaped as `\!` in some shells)