# Specify output format of xslt

Tags: xslt

I know this is asked before but I can't find a simple example. Just trying to change output format. My existing XSLT is this and works but output format is always .txt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <xsl:text>*,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="//AccountFields/AccountID"/>
        <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="//TransactionLine">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="//AccountFields/AccountID"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ItemFields/ItemID"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="TransactionLineFields/UnitQuantity"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="TransactionLineFields/UnitPrice"/>
            <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried adding `<xsl:result-document href="Order.csv" method="text">` but the file fails to generate completely and the tool I'm using doesn't give me a clear way to see errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="Order.csv" method="text">
            <xsl:text>*,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="//AccountFields/AccountID"/>
            <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//TransactionLine">
                <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
                <xsl:value-of select="//AccountFields/AccountID"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ItemFields/ItemID"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="TransactionLineFields/UnitQuantity"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="TransactionLineFields/UnitPrice"/>
                <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the problem you are describing as *"but output format is always .txt."*. What else would you want it to be? If you are trying to set the name and/or the extension of the resulting file, then you are looking in the wrong place: this cannot be controlled by the stylesheet (at least not in XSLT 1.0). It is entirely up to the tool you are you using.to call the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

[xsl:result-document](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xsl-elements/result-document.html) is only available in XSLT 2.0 and later versions.

If you can use XSLT-2.0, you could pass parameters and set the `method` attribute with an attribute value template to

> "xml" | "html" | "xhtml" | "text" | "json" | "adaptive" | eqname

Here, the file extension and the output method are set dynamically by parameters passed to the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="fileExt" select="'.csv'" />
    <xsl:param name="fileMethod" select="'xml'" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="{concat('Order',$fileExt)}" method="{$fileMethod}">
            <xsl:text>*,</xsl:text>
            ...
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It has been tested with Saxon.
If you wanted to change the `xsl:output` method instead, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56446836/1305969).

Comment: Thanks, do you know what Adaptive means? Could I use that to change the file extension to CSV? The documentation just says "adaptive for Adaptive output"

Comment: I added an example to my answer. The output method "adaptive" is described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#adaptive-output), but AFAIK it is only available in XSLT 3.0.