# issue dynamically selecting output format

Tags: xslt-3.0

this is an excerpt of what works

```
<xsl:output method="json" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="dsl" as="element()">
        <epg lastBuildDate="10/4/2019 9:46:00 AM">
        </epg>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="output" as="map(*)*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$output"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

based on

[How to dynamically change xsl:output method attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446836/how-to-dynamically-change-xsloutput-method-attribute-value)

I want to dynamically select the output format, so I've tried (as a starting point), removing the top level output instruction and then using result-document

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="dsl" as="element()">
        <epg lastBuildDate="10/4/2019 9:46:00 AM">
        </epg>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="output" as="map(*)*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:result-document method="json" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
        <xsl:sequence select="$output"/>        
    </xsl:result-document>      
</xsl:template>
```

this gives me (in java saxon 10.6),

```
cannot serialise a map using this method
```

(let me create a complete example as suggested)

I've subsequently edited my example and it works, so I'm not too sure how this didnt work

Comment: Which saxon are you using?  Version? Java? Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me with Saxon-J (Java) version 11.4:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="3.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

    <xsl:param name="method" as="xs:string" />

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$method eq 'json'" >
                <xsl:result-document method="json" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
                    <xsl:map>
                        <xsl:map-entry key="'a'" select="'A'" />
                        <xsl:map-entry key="'b'" select="'B'" />
                    </xsl:map>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:result-document method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="a" value="A" />
                        <entry key="b" value="B" />
                    </map>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Calling from the command line and passing "method" as a parameter:

with "method=xml"

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
   <entry key="a" value="A"/>
   <entry key="b" value="B"/>
</map>
```

with "method=json":

```json
{ "a":"A", "b":"B" }
```

N.B. Saxon-JS (xslt3fiddle) is giving me an error:

```
Error during transformation:
A result document on the base output URI has already been created
```

Obviously, to run in xslt3fiddle, need to provide the value for the parameter.  (Maybe in a future version, xslt3fiddle will accept parameters, @martin-honnen?)

```xml
    <xsl:param name="method" as="xs:string" select="'json'" />
```

Comment: I think the problem with the SaxonJS and simply using `xsl:result-document` with no `href` attribute at all can also be shown running `xslt3` (i.e. the Node.js command line tool of SaxonJS) from the command line, although it exhibits itself with a different error "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory". As for the xslt3fiddle accepting parameters, you can do that by editing in a default value with e.g. `select` (as you have done) or with content of the `xsl:param`.  I am not sure a separate interface for adding parameter values would add any value to the fiddle tool.

Comment: hmmmm.....I can't recreate the issue, it works, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I got some feedback on Twitter from another user of the xslt3, SaxonJS based fiddle, that resulted in this prototype page https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/index-params.html to allow setting global parameters value in a dialog instead of directly in the XSLT code. As you, @al.truisme, also seemed to want such a feature, it would be interesting to know if the now implemented workflow also suits your expectactions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps give a minimal but complete sample, together with details of the Saxon version and how exactly you run it, but [at the online fiddle using Saxon HE 11 Java](https://https:/https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22dsl%22%20as%3D%22element%28%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cepg%20lastBuildDate%3D%2210%2F4%2F2019%209%3A46%3A00%20AM%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fepg%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22output%22%20as%3D%22map%28*%29*%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%24dsl%22%20mode%3D%22interpret%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20method%3D%22json%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22%24output%22%2F%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22epg%22%20as%3D%22map%28*%29%22%20mode%3D%22interpret%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22map%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27lastBuildDate%27%20%3A%20%40lastBuildDate%20%3D%3E%20xs%3Astring%28%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Ctest%2F%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML/) in the backend, I can't reproduce the problem (assumed the construction of the map from your previous question/answer is supposed to be added).

This goes as an intermediary answer as I can't put all those details in a comment, will delete it if it becomes clear what fails for you and this response does not resolve it.